# Python Selenium find_elements not giving me the current element

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium in Python and looping to constantly check the first child of the `row` element as it constantly changes, however for some reason when the first child of `row` changes, the `ele` variable still remains the same, any solutions?

```py
row = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'row')[3]
while looprunning:
    ele= row.find_element(By.XPATH,"./child::*")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the `row` as well,

```
while looprunning:
    row = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'row')[3]
    ele = row.find_element(By.XPATH,"./child::*")
```

Comment: even if i refresh 'row' on my loop, it still gives me the same element even though it has already changed